# Why am I receiving a Conflicting peer dependency about multer when installing dayjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer, dayjs, multer-gridfs-storage

When I try to install dayjs I receive this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: multer-gridfs-storage@5.0.2
npm ERR! Found: multer@1.4.5-lts.1
npm ERR! node_modules/multer
npm ERR!   multer@"^1.4.5-lts.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer multer@"^1.4.2" from multer-gridfs-storage@5.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/multer-gridfs-storage
npm ERR!   multer-gridfs-storage@"^5.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: multer@1.4.4
npm ERR! node_modules/multer
npm ERR!   peer multer@"^1.4.2" from multer-gridfs-storage@5.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/multer-gridfs-storage
npm ERR!     multer-gridfs-storage@"^5.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!
```

Gridfs and multer is all working fine and I only get this error when installing dayjs.
can somebody tell me what's going on and how to fix this issue, please?

Many thanks

Comment: Please also post your `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to multer version 4.